# How to manipulate `@input` - by conditionally

Tags: angular

I am getting value by `@Input()` - I require to manipulate using the iterator, how to do that?

Here is my code :

```
@Input() events: Observable<Array<CalendarEvent>>; //required manipulation
@Input() currentEvent: ModelEvent;

clickedDate: Date;

constructor(private calendarService:CalendarService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    const headerHeight = $('.site-header').outerHeight();
    //moving content down to header
    $('body').css({paddingTop: headerHeight});

    this.calendarService.eventId.subscribe(event => {
        this.eventId = event.id;
        this.setViewDate();
    })

    // this.events.subscribe(data => console.log('data', data));

    if(this.events.length) { //how to do? //at present getting error
        <!-- do something -->
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain bit more what you getting error and what you want to do?

Comment: I am getting the events from parent component, when the events available in child, i require to add id in each of event and pass to template

Comment: Can you post the code for the calendarService as well?

Comment: @dileepkumarjami - there is no service, getting value from parent. parent getting it from `ngrx/store` -

Comment: You seem to have a wrong understanding of  the `Observable` class in `rxjs`. You might want to look at some documentation about it before moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ask for the length of an observable, and you therefore get an error. Instead you should subscribe and then move the if-statement inside the callback function where you can use the value of events to do exactly what you want.

Comment: When I try like this : `this.events.subscribe(data => console.log('data', data));` getting error as `this.events.subscribe is not a function` - any idea?

Comment: Are you sure that you are giving the component an observable as input?

Comment: here is my code `<ibo-calendar 
 [events]="events$ | async"
 [currentEvent]="currentEvent$ | async"
></ibo-calendar>`

Comment: You are using the async pipe and you are therefore not injecting an observable but instead the actual array. Just remove the observable part of your input-type and you should be good to go. Then you can work directly with events and don't have to subscribe in your component.

Comment: I.e. your input becomes: Input() events: Array<CalendarEvent>;

Comment: still i can't subscribe rigtht?

Comment: getting result as `events []` - any idea?

Comment: You are subscribing when you use the async pipe. You therefore cannot do it again in the component retrieving events as input. You can instead just manipulate events as a regular array in this component.

Comment: Nope, getting nothing as output.. `this.events.forEach(item => console.log('item', item));`

Comment: Are you sure that the array of events contains any calendar events?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188573/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-tobias-thornfeldt-nissen).